# Google Admob crash fix in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, google-ads-api

I implemented the google admob to my unity application but when I press the button the game crash out.
What did I something do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you using git, or someone else control version, reset your progress to point when all was good, after that try install admob (or batter reinstall all IronSource), after each step push comit for safty reset your progress if something will happen.

You dont show your errors, so i can't give you another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Asset -> Google Mobile ads Setting
fill AdMob App ID there.

Google Mobile Ads Settings:

[image]